# R - web scraping date picker

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to use R to web scrape stock data from here https://markets.ft.com/data/equities/tearsheet/historical?s=RICHTER:BUD, but I don't know  how to change the date range.

I'm using rvest::html_form, but I was not able to even identify which form should I alter and also wasn't able to set_values of any form on the webpage.

I'd be grateful if someone just could show some guidelines.

Many thanks

Comment: Take a look at the `lubridate` package to manage dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple because the website seems to accept parameters **inside** the URL. Then, with respect to the example you posted, if you want to retrieve data between - let's say - January 1st 2017 and June 30th 2017, you could easily fetch the following url:

```
https://markets.ft.com/data/equities/ajax/get-historical-prices?startDate=2017%2F01%2F01&endDate=2017%2F06%2F30&symbol=136642
```

where `symbol=136642` stands for the `RICHTER:BUD` ticker, as you could find through a `GET` command on the original URL.

Hope it helps!